# Running multiple tasks parrallel and overwriting each line in for

Tags: c#, task, text-cursor

I'm pretty new to programming, but I have a question:

How could I show different task output (*I should use the tasks*) in different lines, in the console?
Also, I want to overwrite the lines each time , so the output should show:

i // overwriting this line everytime.

j // overwriting this line everytime.

I tried using *SetCursorPosition*, but it makes a collision between the task ouput somewhy.

***A mini code sample (hope this makes it clearer):***

```
Task a = Task.Run(() =>
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i <= 1000000; i++)
    {
        Console.SetCursorPosition(Console.CursorLeft, 0); // ? 
        Console.WriteLine("{0}", i);
    }
});

Task b = Task.Run(() =>
{
    int j;
    for (j = 0; j <= 1000000; j++)
    {
        Console.SetCursorPosition(Console.CursorLeft, 3); // ?
        Console.WriteLine("{0}",j);
    }
});

Console.ReadLine();
```

Thank You in advance :)

Comment: Do you want i & j in separate lines? As of now, you are writing in same line.

Comment: Yes, I would like in seperate lines

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to synchronize access to `Console` for different tasks (I am not fixing position part if there is any problem, but an obvious synchronization problem):

```
var consoleLock = new object();

Task.Run(() =>
{
    for (int i = 0; i <= 1000000; i++)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(1); // to simulate some work
        lock(consoleLock)
        {
            Console.SetCursorPosition(Console.CursorLeft, 0);
            Console.WriteLine(i);
        }
    }
});

Task.Run(() =>
{
    for (int j = 0; j <= 1000000; j++)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(1); // to simulate some work
        lock(consoleLock)
        {
            Console.SetCursorPosition(Console.CursorLeft, 3);
            Console.WriteLine(j);
        }
    }
});

Console.ReadLine();
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a simplified demo of what you are trying. Modify it as per your needs.

The basic idea is, you call a `ThreadSafe` method to write to console from all threads. And, every time you update the console, you re-write the two lines (notice the use of `SetCursorPosition()` method).

```
static object locker = new object();
static int iCommon = 0;
static int jCommon = 0;

static void WriteText()
{
    lock(locker)
    {
        var text = string.Format("i = {0}{1}j = {2}", 
                                    iCommon, Environment.NewLine, jCommon);
        Console.SetCursorPosition(0, 
                                  Console.CursorTop == 0 ? 0 : Console.CursorTop - 1);
        Console.Write(text);
    }
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Task a = Task.Run(() =>
    {
        for (int i = 0; i <= 15; i++)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(700); //just to demonstrate the display change
            iCommon = i;
            WriteText();
        }
    });

    Task b = Task.Run(() =>
    {
        for (int j = 0; j <= 10; j++)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(1150); //just to demonstrate the display change
            jCommon = j;
            WriteText();
        }
    });
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Comment: Thank You very much! I'll surely upvote, when I'll have enough reputation! :)

Comment: @Yogi You are welcome. Do you need more reputation to upvote? I though that is allowed for everyone! Anyway, this method should do exactly what you are trying. Check it out, and upvote when you can :)